# Array in other formate

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, laravel-5

I am working on restfull api's for mobile app development. I am returning an php array in json which is like,

```
"data": {
    "Waxing": [
        {
            "id": "119",
            "provider_id": "54",
            "provider_service_id": "0",
            "category_id": "15",
            "date": "09-06-2018",
            "time": "08.00 AM,10.00 AM,11.00 AM,12.00 PM,01.00 PM,02.00 PM,03.00 PM,04.00 PM,05.00 PM,06.00 PM,07.00 PM",
            "repeat": "D",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2018-06-09 05:22:47",
            "updated_at": "2018-06-09 14:22:04",
            "setdate": "09 Jun",
            "name": "Waxing"
        }
    ],
    "Massage": [
        {
            "id": "145",
            "provider_id": "54",
            "provider_service_id": "0",
            "category_id": "4",
            "date": "14-06-2018",
            "time": "08.00 AM,09.00 AM,10.00 AM,11.00 AM,12.00 PM,01.00 PM,02.00 PM,03.00 PM,04.00 PM,05.00 PM,06.00 PM,07.00 PM",
            "repeat": "O",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2018-06-13 14:24:15",
            "updated_at": "2018-06-13 14:24:15",
            "setdate": "14 Jun",
            "name": "Massage"
        }
    ]
},
```

and creating this output with these line of code:

```
        foreach ($getproviderdatetime as $getproviderdatetimes){
            $categorycheck = Category::where('id', '=', $getproviderdatetimes->category_id)->first();
            if(count($categorycheck)>0){
               $alldata[$categorycheck->name][]=$getproviderdatetimes;
            }                
        }
```

but now I need data in this format:

```
"data": {
  [
    "categoryname": "Waxing",
    "services": [
        {
            "id": "119",
            "provider_id": "54",
            "provider_service_id": "0",
            "category_id": "15",
            "date": "09-06-2018",
            "time": "08.00 AM,10.00 AM,11.00 AM,12.00 PM,01.00 PM,02.00 PM,03.00 PM,04.00 PM,05.00 PM,06.00 PM,07.00 PM",
            "repeat": "D",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2018-06-09 05:22:47",
            "updated_at": "2018-06-09 14:22:04",
            "setdate": "09 Jun",
            "name": "Waxing"
        }
    ]
  ],
  [
    "categoryname": "massage",
    "services": [
        {
            "id": "145",
            "provider_id": "54",
            "provider_service_id": "0",
            "category_id": "4",
            "date": "14-06-2018",
            "time": "08.00 AM,09.00 AM,10.00 AM,11.00 AM,12.00 PM,01.00 PM,02.00 PM,03.00 PM,04.00 PM,05.00 PM,06.00 PM,07.00 PM",
            "repeat": "O",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2018-06-13 14:24:15",
            "updated_at": "2018-06-13 14:24:15",
            "setdate": "14 Jun",
            "name": "Massage"
        }
    ]
  ]
},
```

I have array of services and getting category name from database. I am using Laravel framework and returning data in json format. How can I achive this. Need help.

Comment: You can't. Here you have same keys `services` and `categoryname`, keys __must be__ unique.

Comment: actually name key in service may differ from the categoryname, sorry but in this example I got the same from by db.

Comment: `categoryname` is key name, it can't appear more than __once__.

Comment: sorry but his is what my app team is required and I am getting stuck into it

Comment: Your team __obviously__ required slightly another format, otherwise your team is low-skilled.

Comment: do you have better idea? Please help me

Comment: sorry my mistake..

Comment: I suppose your team need `data` as array of objects. That's my idea, but it's better to ask team for clarification.

Comment: Sorry now I edited my question to what they really want. Please help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173173/discussion-between-cody-and-u-mulder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
foreach ($getproviderdatetime as $getproviderdatetimes){
    $categorycheck = Category::where('id', '=', $getproviderdatetimes->category_id)->first();
    if(count($categorycheck)>0){
       // append new item to all data:
       $alldata[] = [
           "categoryname" => $categorycheck->name,
           "services" => [$getproviderdatetimes],
       ];
    }                
}
```

Comment: Thanks @u_mulder. but now I am getting object for each service [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1gvmc8L/)

Comment: And that's fine. Array is only for 0-indexed keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $testing = []
    foreach ($alldata as $key=>$all){
    array_push($testing,["categoryname"=>$key,"services"=>$all]);
    }
    print_r($testing);
```

Loop again ur $alldata..Bellow is ur solution

https://3v4l.org/9iT9l